# How to add peer nodes to an existing running Hyperledger fabric blockchain using Hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

My Hyperledger fabric blockchain is already up and running using Hyperledger composer. Now I want to add one more peer node that should be running on physically different machine. What will be the steps for extending blockchain and I already issued PeerAdmin card and few others user cards with all peer nodes IP entries. Do I also need to add IP address of newly added node in the cards?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924385/hyperledger-composer-add-a-new-peer or https://discourse.skcript.com/t/setting-up-a-blockchain-business-network-with-hyperledger-fabric-composer-running-in-multiple-physical-machine/602/141 (peer on different physical machine, same org - needs to update added references on config files to use/download Fabric 1.2.1 images FYI)

Comment: see this tutorial (albeit on 1.1 - you can find equivalent for 1.2.1 ) -> https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217